# Use parameter of php function as column name in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is for a school project. I am new in PHP and MySQL.
I am trying to write a function in PHP with one string parameter, which will become the column name of a SQL query which is used in a prepare() statement inside this function.

Here is the code:

```
function checkCredentials($dbFieldToCheck) {
  $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE ".$dbFieldToCheck." = ? AND password = PASSWORD(?)");
  if (!$statement) die("Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error);
  $statement->bind_param("ss", $_POST["username/email"], $_POST["password"]);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->get_result();
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  return $row;
}
```

Then I call this function twice in two different variables:

```
$row1 = checkCredentials('email');
$row2 = checkCredentials('username');
```

Finally I do something with these two variables (not useful here I guess).

I have tried different ways to write the parameter in the SQL statement also different ways to write it in the function call. Now I am even starting to think that my function is not even called at all...

What I want to achieve works if I just execute the code inside the function two times with the column name hard coded. But this is not nice :)

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Start with checking value of `$conn` in your function.

Comment: You might have declared `$conn` outside of your function. You can use `global $conn` to call the variable inside your function.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. Yes I know. I actually removed a comment next to the password that said "Do not do this is production!" :) Thanks for your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to the parameter of your function the submitted `POST` data and your connection variable. When you call your function, it will look like this:

```
checkCredentials($dbFieldToCheck, $conn, $_POST["username/email"], $_POST["password"]);
```

Your function will look something like this:

```
function checkCredentials(string $dbFieldToCheck, $conn, $username, $password) {

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE ".$dbFieldToCheck." = ? AND password = PASSWORD(?)");
    if (!$statement) die("Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error);
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row;

}
```

You can use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to call variables inside your function (*you can refer here for the cons of using [`global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)*).

Comment: thanks this worked. For some reason I also had to remove the type "string" in my function signature for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your function doesn't know about `$conn` because it wasn't declared in its scope.
Your function should begin like this :

```
global $conn;
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information about variable scope.

**EDIT :**

As [apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) pointed out in the comments, the use of `global` is not recommended. It would be better to pass `$conn` as a parameter to `checkCredentials`.

See [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions) for details. Quote :

> A function call should not have to rely on anything outside

Comment: The use of `global` is not recommended. Better pass the `$conn` variable as a parameter.

Comment: Why are you guessing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can modify your code like this:

```
$servername = "localhost:3306";//replace with your mysql server address
$username = "username";//replace with your mysql user
$password = "password";//replace with your mysql password

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";


function checkCredentials(string $dbFieldToCheck, $conn, $username, $password) {

    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE ".$dbFieldToCheck." = ? AND password = PASSWORD(?)");
    if (!$statement) die("Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error);
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row;
}
checkCredentials('email');
```

Using PHP with MYSQL is not complex, this doc can help you get the basic idea how they work together
(http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).

Comment: You guess? Why would you guess?